# Proof that $X_t=(t-T)^+$, where $T$ is exponentially distributed, defines a Markov process $(X_t)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $(\mathbb{R}^{+}, \mathbb{B}, P)$ be a probability space with probability $P$ given by its distribution function

$$F(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 - e^{-y} &, y\ge 0\\
0 &,\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.$$

Let $X_t(w) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0   &, w\ge t\\
t-w &, 0<w<t 
\end{array}\right.\quad $ be a stochastic process, with $w\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Is it a Markov process?

My answer was no, because (with $0 < u < s < t$):

$$P[X_t = 0\mid X_s \in (-\infty, s]] = \frac{P([t,+\infty) \cap \mathbb{R}^{+})}{P[X_s \in (-\infty, s]]} = \frac{P([t,+\infty) \cap \mathbb{R}^{+})}{P(\mathbb{R}^{+})} = P([t, +\infty))$$

that is not the same as:

$$P[X_t = 0\mid X_u \in (-\infty, 0], X_s \in (-\infty, s]] = \frac{P([t,+\infty))}{P([u, +\infty))} = \frac{P([t, +\infty))}{1-F(u)}$$

The professor told me my argument was wrong, but I don't know why. In case it is indeed a Markov process, could you give a proof?

Comment: I think this might be easier to read with the parenthesis notation for open intervals rather than the backwards bracket notation, i.e. $(a,b)$ instead of $]a,b[$.

Comment: Markov property is **not** that $$P(X_t\in A\mid X_s\in B,X_u\in C)=P(X_t\in A\mid X_s\in B)$$ for every $(A,B,C)$ and $u<s<t$, it only implies that $$P(X_t\in A\mid X_s=x,X_u\in C)=P(X_t\in A\mid X_s=x)$$ for every $(A,C)$ and $x$, and $u<s<t$. Thus, one must condition on the exact location of $X_s$. A proof that the process you are looking at is indeed Markov, should follow readily.

Comment: Later on, you might be asked to prove that this process $(X_t)$ is not strongly Markov, giving you a nice example that in continuous time the simple and strong Markov properties are indeed different.

Comment: I guess key fact here is that, if you know the value of the process up to time t, $X_t$, you then know all the path the process followed to reach that value.

Comment: Thanks @Did .
I think the definition of Markov property is my problem here. Could you give me a reference about where to read a proper definition of Markov property?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property#Definition

Comment: @Kolmo Exactly. In other words, $$\sigma(X_s;s\leqslant t)=\sigma(X_t)$$

Comment: @Did I don't see the characterization you gave in the above link, and clearly it doesn't hold in general that $\sigma(X_s; s\le t) = \sigma(X_t)$

Comment: "I don't see the characterization you gave in the above link" ??? This is the first displayed equation in the link. "clearly it doesn't hold in general that..." Clearly, indeed, but who said or even imagined that it was true in general? Only, in the present case, it does hold. (Sorry but I am not sure the approach displayed in your last comment is the most constructive one that one can imagine in your situation...)

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself poorly. I haven't been able to find a characterization of Markov property written as $P(X_t \in A \mid X_{t_1} \in B_1, \ldots X_{t_{n-1}} \in B_{n-1}, X_{t_n} = x) = P(X_t \in \mid X_{t_{n-1}} = x), \quad t_1 < \ldots < t_n < t$, nor in the wiki or anywhere else. Respect to the proof of this being a Markov process, sorry, I had just read again your argument and it's absolutely correct.

Comment: $\sigma(X_s;s \leq t)=\sigma(X_t)$ does not hold in general even under the Mairkov property. All that holds is the conditional probability of *future* events given $\sigma(X_s;s \leq t)$ is the same as that given $\sigma(X_t)$. Past events won't do this, so the $\sigma$-algebras themselves are not the same.

Comment: It does however hold in this particular problem, which is sufficient for the Markov property.